# Decorated function along with original, without having to re-write the function

Tags: python, metaprogramming, decorator, python-decorators

If I have a decorator and a function, but I would like to use the decorated function along with the undecorated version of that function, what would I do?

I haven't used decorators much and from what I can find, it seems as if you would have to write out 2 separate functions to accomplish this, or call the decorator with the function as the parameter which can be somewhat confusing when dealing with multiple decorators.

To work around this, I am writing out a function, then I use a somewhat roundabout way of decorating the function and returning that decorated function after the fact.  So I have access to both the undecorated and the decorated versions of that function.  From what I can tell, the method in which this is accomplished is looked down upon a little bit, but it has been working for me *so far*.  I cannot imagine that this is the best way to go about this.

Essentially, I pass the function I want to decorate, along with the decorator functions, to a method that inspects the functions text, adds the `@decorator` syntax to the text, then it adds the decorator functions into the `__builtins__` module temporarily so I can `exec` the text into a dictionary to define the new decorated function.  This new function object is extracted from the dictionary and is returned as the new decorated function.

I'm pretty sure this is *not* the best way to go about this.  I don't imagine it would work in all situations, but I also don't want to have to call the decorated functions or rewrite the function every time.

Comment: Why don't you just use `function(...)` directly when you need it, and `decorator(function)(...)` when you need the decorated version?

Comment: @jonsharpe, I was wondering if there was another way to do it.  I could easily just do it that way, but I figured I would ask.

Comment: *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it"* (`import this`), and this is it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the decorator as a decorator then. Remember, a decorator is syntactic sugar, but you don't *have* to use it.

The syntax:

```
@decorator_expr
def decorated_func():
    pass
```

is really executed as:

```
def decorated_func():
    pass
decorated_func = decorator_expr(decorated_func)
```

To keep the 'original' and a decorated version, then, just assign the output of the decorator to a different name:

```
def foo():
    pass

foo_decorated = decorator_expr(foo)
```

Alternatively, use the decorator callable every time you need a decorated version:

```
result = decorator_expr(foo)()
```

Comment: Ok, I see now.  I realize that you can call the decorator with the function as the argument for the same behavior, but I didn't realize you can give it it's own callable name.  Thanks!

Comment: @DuckPuncher: In Python, functions (and other callables, like bound methods) are first-class objects, just like numbers or strings or anything else. So, you can assign them to names, call them by those names, pass them to functions as arguments, etc.